# How to prevent Place submission approval?

Tags: google-places-api

Is there a way to sandbox (for testing) the Place/Events submissions so they are not approved (so they are not submitted to the moderation queue)?

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions

says:

"New Places will be available immediately in Place Searches initiated by your application, and will enter the moderation queue to be considered for Google Maps. A newly-added Place will not be available to other applications until it has been approved by the moderation process."

Thanks

Fred

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to prevent Place/Event submissions from being submitted for moderation.

Answer (score 0):

Currently only requests submitted from a small number of trusted applications are being moderated for integration into Google Places.